# Dynamic Custom Field in Template based on client selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My requirement is making a dynamic custom field in view page.

eg:- Customer will have master where they can mention which filed has to show in front-end to users. suppose there is a Customer A they want to show birth-date and Customer B want to show the Age in front-end. This both birth-date and age i have in table but it should visible in front-end based on customer selection. Can anyone help me how we can achieve this in Ruby on Rails. Is that any gem or plug-in available for this. Or is it possible to do it our own way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can outsmart by creating a new table. example: `user_frontend` with `style_type` `user_id` field. `style_type` use this to store the type. You can Define `0` => `default frontend`, `1` => `age`, `2` => `birthday`

hope this help you, cheers.

Comment: yes i can do that. But i want some better solution to show in front-end. The way you mention i can store into table for each customer which field has to show. But how i will retrieve in the form_for for each customer only those respective fields.

Comment: Controller frontend

`def index
   @user = User.All
   respond_to do |format|
   format.html # new.html.erb
   format.xml { render :xml => @article }
   end
end`

Model User
`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  
   def style_user_front
      case style_type  #assumse have table name "style_type"
     when 0
    #use default
  when 1
    "#{age}" #put age
  when 2
    "#{birthday}" #put bithday
   end
end`
#controller
`User.all`
#view
`f.style_user_front`